# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk__init__'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container=tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
    continer.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
```

Help me please I watch it on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gaXfM1UN0&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&index=2 but it did not work on me

Comment: It's `tk.Tk.__init__`, not `tk.Tk__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `super()` instead of `Tk.__init__()`

```
from tkinter import Tk

class CustomGui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomGui,self).__init__()
```